# Android - expand/collapse list view without using expandablelistview

Tags: android

Can someone point me to the right direction or how I would go about in making my listview expand/collapse like the expandablelistview without using the expandablelistview?

The reason is I am trying to merge multiple list views together using CWC MergeAdapter and the MergeAdapter does not accept a ExpandableListAdapter so I would need to code in the collapse/expand on a regular listview.

Unless someone out there knows how I can add an ExpandableListAdapter to a Merge Adapter?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is ExpandableListViews have been phased out because they're not a preferred design solution.  My first suggestion is to think of alternate navigation methods.

If you absolutely need expandable functionality you will have to make your own ListView that contains views that are dividers and views that represent content.  When you click a divider, it sets the visibility of the content views it cares about to View.VISIBLE and then when you want to hide it you can use View.GONE.  But, this imitates a normal ExpandableListView so why not just flatten the ExpandableListView when you need to merge it?

Comment: Great idea, I did not think of it.  So I've inflate a layout with an ExpandableListView and I set the ExpandableListAdapter to it.  I then use MergeAdapter.addView() method to it.  However, for some reason, it is not calling the ExpandableListAdapter getChildViews method.  Is there particular reason why?